# SQL/Access Expression Custom Sort

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a challenging sorting issue I can't solve via SQL or Expression Builder.  So let's say I have 'Group 1' which is the names of ten applications.  Sorting this group is easy enough in access.  Each system has a set of exchanges with a provider and a consumer.  where it gets tricky is a secondary sort on first the name of the sending system and then a-z.  see my example below:

Inventory Management System (L1)

1. Asset Management System (L2)
2. Service Management System (L2)
3. Inventory Management System (L2)
4. Computer Management System (L2)

Sorting at the "L1" level is no problem, but below that I want my first "L2" record to match the L1 record, and then after that it can be A-Z.

In the above Example, I ideally want it to look like this:

Inventory Management System (L1)

1. Inventory Management System (L2)
2. Asset Management Management System (L2)
3. Computer Management System (L2)
4. Service Management System (L2)

the logic would go something like if any L2 values are equal to an L1 value, then list those first, and anything that is not equal to the L1 value can be sorted ascending.

Comment: @Gordon, please watch your tagging! The last time someone created `access`, I was cleaning it up for a week.  :/

Comment: @Charles . . . Thank you for the warning.  I'll be more careful about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
order by l1,
         iif(l2 = l1, 0, 1),
         l2
```

Answer (score 0):

so I have found a partial solution using your code above.  my results now look like this

Inventory Management System (L1)

Inventory Management System (L2)

Inventory Management System (L2)
Application Management System
Network Management System (L2)

this is where it gets tricky.  Access is interpreting all results that do not match L1 to be an entire new value.  I got the first part of the solution as the sorting is custom based on the L2 name but all the other values associated with the L1 name, they are now being sorted as a separate value.

my code is =IIf(([OriginNode])=([APPNAME]),0,1)

I think if I move the sort below the L1 grouping this would solve it but then I get

Order by clause conflicts with group by clause???